# Kusto query to exclude results from a certain time (Ex. Thursday from midnight-2am EST)

Tags: datetime, configuration, azure-data-explorer

I am newer to KQL and I am trying to write a query against configuration changes made to files with an extension of ".config" and would like to remove results that are generated under the "TimeGenerated [UTC]" column.  **The results should exclude Thursday's from midnight- 2am EST**.  Would someone be able to assist me in writing this? Not sure how to write it up as to have it return the results that exclude the specific time frame. Below is what I have so far:

```
ConfigurationChange
| where ConfigChangeType in("Files")
| where FileSystemPath contains ".config"
| sort by TimeGenerated
| render table
```

Comment: In running the query again today it appears that it is not excluding the time frame of Thursday's from midnight-2amEST.  Any thoughts? Below is what I have:

```
ConfigurationChange
| where dayofweek(datetime_add('hour', -5, TimeGenerated)) != 4d and hourofday(datetime_add('hour', -5, TimeGenerated)) !in(0, 1) // <---
| where ConfigChangeType in ("Files")
| where FileSystemPath endswith ".config"
| sort by TimeGenerated
| render table
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the following filter, using [`dayofweek()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/dayofweekfunction) and [`hourofday()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/hourofdayfunction).

**Note:** The example below works in UTC. You can add the current offset of UTC -> EST to `TimeGenerated` as part of the filter

```
ConfigurationChange
| where dayofweek(TimeGenerated) != 6d and hourofday(TimeGenerated) !in(0, 1) // <---
| where ConfigChangeType in ("Files")
| where FileSystemPath contains ".config"
| sort by TimeGenerated
| render table
```

Comment: Thank you, this helped point me in the right direction.  To get what I needed, this is where I landed:    

ConfigurationChange
| where dayofweek(datetime_add('hour',-5, TimeGenerated)) != 4d and hourofday(datetime_add('hour',-5,TimeGenerated)) !in(0, 1) // <---
| where ConfigChangeType in ("Files")
| where FileSystemPath contains ".config"
| sort by TimeGenerated
| render table